# Java Business Intelligence framework with ad-hoc web reporting?

Tags: java, grails, groovy, reporting, business-intelligence

I need a reporting framework that supports web views with ad-hoc reporting, as well as styled, canned PDF reports.

My users will be non-power users, so I'll need to present something usable for the ad-hoc reporting.

What's the best current solution in the java world?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [jasper reports plugin](http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/puneetbehl/jasper) for grails

Not used it yet myself tho...

Comment: Forget the plugin. It's easier to integrate manually.

Answer (score 2):

Candidates are Eclipse BIRT, JasperReports (has Grails plugin), Google Chart (has a Grails plugin I think), Pentaho and possibly Flying Saucer (Grails plugin named "rendering") if you just want the PDF generation and do the reporting yourself with eg JFreeChart.

However, you probably won't find much of ad-hoc reporting in those tools and I believe it to be hard to make a generic ad-hoc tool. It's hard to give a final recommendation since they all have their strength and weaknesses.

Answer (score 0):

check out pentaho. it's open-source, free to use, but has paid support model

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the number of users you have and the amount of money you want to spend, Inetsoft's product line might work for you.  It's a java web app that allows you to create simple logical data models which users can then use to create adhoc reports.

Our organization has had success with it on a small scale, but have encountered a lot of issues trying to scale it for 2000+ users.

Comment: StyleReports is one of the most heinous toolsuites I've ever had to use.