# Are there any adhoc report builder libraries available in Java/ Groovy ? That generate SQL queries based on dimensions/measures selected

Tags: java, business-intelligence

Ideally the library needs a detailing of what tables/columns/aggregation each dimension/measure map to. Then when given the list of selected ones it generates the SQL querie(s)

Comment: dimensions and measures of what? a pre-existing database schema?

Comment: yes a rdbms scehema, oracle in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Probably what you need is a generic layer to access the underlying analytical database, like [OLAP4J](http://www.olap4j.org) which provide API layer to the underlying analytical databases.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it myself, but I've heard good things about [Pentaho](http://www.pentaho.com/).  Java based and open source.

Comment: actually what i am trying to build is a pentaho type Business Intelligencec tool. Instead of using the readymade deisnger and visualisations from Pentaho, i want to use my own UI layer and build a query generator below it.

Comment: I think I read the other day that you can use Pentaho as a java library you don't need to run the gui on top of it. But I've not tried myself.

Answer (score 0):

See also this question here: [Java Business Intelligence framework with ad-hoc web reporting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144343/java-business-intelligence-framework-with-ad-hoc-web-reporting) and the linked [jasper plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/jasper) for Groovy. However, ad hoc query is very seldom and I am currently facing the same problems.

I think that Adhoc queries for BIRT and JasperSoft are offered only in the "Enterprise" (read "commercial") solution. I am trying to implement it in a way that the creater of the report can provide parameters (special marked) and that the end user can choose to include or exclude this parameters. This is not particulary "Ad hoc", but will be enough for my customers requirements.

Comment: There is a Community Edition of Jasper Reports Server. You can see the comparison chart at http://www.jaspersoft.com/editions.

Comment: There is no longer a community edition it seems. Pity, because it looks to be pretty good!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to generate a query easily from several databases you can try [Active Query Builder](http://www.activequerybuilder.com/product_java.html), it's graphic (let you drop down tables), dead simple to put in your program and is easily customizable (to some extent), this coupled perhaps with JasperReports or with a simple grid, may help you to do what you want.

Comment: we do not want to expose the end used to sql or schema structure, but instead create a adhoc model, from which he can drag/drop objects. The based on what the user has selected, need to generate query at the back.